# Отображение большого количества объектов

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Нужно отобразить на карте ~5000 объектов, без использования их объединения в круги(кластеры). Объекты имеют кастомный хинт(с фотографиями) и при перемещении мыши по ним карта тормозит.Возможно ли сделать кластеризацию такми образом, чтобы вместо большого круга просто показывался один объект из этого кластера, а при увеличении масштаба начинали появляться остальные? (т.е. уменьшить кол-во объектов вместо их объединения в круги) Используется objectManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уменьшение количества объектов и есть кластеризация, иначе задача звучит противоречиво.

У кластера может быть хинт, как и у вложенных объектов. В поле hint кластера можно отображать хинт первого объекта из этого кластера. Обратите внимание на параметры hasHint и ClusterHintLayout. Модифицируя пример из песочницы https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manage:

```
function init () {

var ClusterHintLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
  '{{ object.features[0].properties.hintContent | raw }}');

var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 10
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
        clusterize: true,
        clusterHasHint: true,
        // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
        gridSize: 32,
        clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
        clusterHintContentLayout: ClusterHintLayout,
        clusterBalloonContentLayout: "cluster#balloonCarousel"
    });

// Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
// обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

objectManager.add(data);
```

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Template-docpage/ о шаблонизаторе.